# Can't build plugin because of circular dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, build, eclipse-plugin, circular-dependency

My plugin consists of a collection of other plugins written by myself and these plugins have circular dependencies in their class paths (and I don't see a way to remove those because the plugins rely on each other).
The plugin runs just fine when testing after I have set eclipse to mark those dependencies as warnings and not as errors. However when I try to build my plugin via the site.xml or the export wizard it always tells me

```
A cycle was detected when generating the classpath  
raven.sqdev.preferences_0.2.0, raven.sqdev.util_0.3.0,  
raven.sqdev.preferences_0.2.0.
```

and quits the building process.
I already found the option to allow circular dependencies in the export wizard but the result stays the same.

Has anyone an idea how I can build my plugin with these circular dependencies?

Comment: Circular dependency is not a good idea, and most of the time it points to a design problem. Try to break one of the projects to two projects: one with the  dependency code and one without. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: I tried and apart of messing up all of my projects I just figured out that I can't split my projects up... Any idea why this isn't building although it runs?